# Why Questions tab does not has "my tags" section?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design

Why does the Questions section not have a "my tags" tab like the one available in Unanswered section?  I find it quite helpful.

> [image: Unanswered section]

Versus

> [image: Questions section]